# How carbon water filter can build air pressure inside (before installation)?

Tags: pressure, water, air

Today I got a new refrigerator carbon water filter. Before installing, out of curiosity, I dripped a bit water into the filter’s outlet to see if water could flow in and out. Obviously it did… Then, distracted by something else, I put the cap back on the filter and walked away. Several minutes later I heard a fairly loud pop sound. The cap popped out. So the filter must have been building up air pressure inside. I wonder how. Does it have anything to do how activated carbon interact with water? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd first think of thermal expansion of the air.

What temperature was the water?  If it was initially colder than room temperature, it could cool and contract any residual air in the filter, but after capping that cooled air would expand as it warmed back up to room temperature.  If it was initially warmer than room temperature and it did not heat up all the carbon before capping, after capping it might have continued to heat air trapped in the carbon which might then be released and expand.